# Running a Chainlink Node - Remote DATABASE_URL Config PostgreSQL problem

Tags: postgresql, docker, ubuntu, nodes, chainlink

I have been trying since yesterday to connect to a **ChainLink** node and I was not able to.
I followed the steps at [this website](https://docs.chain.link/docs/running-a-chainlink-node#config)
I am having a problem with "Set the Remote DATABASE_URL Config" (I think that this is my only error because of the [ERROR] listed below, I do not know if I am doing something else wrong since every command was executed without error)

I am using the Docker option to create the database [listed here](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/).

**I am always having this error:**

"[ERROR] unable to lock ORM: failed to connect to `host=localhost user=some-postgres database=postgres`: dial error (dial tcp [::1]:5432: connect: cannot assign requested address) logger/default.go:155   stacktrace=github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/logger.Errorf
/chainlink/core/logger/default.go:155"

**After writing in my Ubuntu Terminal (ON WINDOWS 10):**

"cd ~/.chainlink-kovan && docker run -p 6688:6688 -v ~/.chainlink-kovan:/chainlink -it --env-file=.env smartcontract/chainlink:0.10.1 local n"

I do not know how to connect to the database and what to write as attributes. All of the other steps and installs I have accomplished successfully.

I just want to know how to create a database on **PostgreSQL** and connect it to **Docker** as explained on the ChainLink website and write the appropriate command in the Ubunto terminal (for the "Remote DATABASE_URL Config PostgreSQL" step) so that I can run my node.

Thanks! (PS: I am a beginner and your help is much appreciated, and if I forgot to mention any important information please let me know so that I add it)

Answer (score 1):

A comprehensive 101 for docker-postgres can be found here: https://hackernoon.com/dont-install-postgres-docker-pull-postgres-bee20e200198

Basically, you need to deploy a postgres db with docker
Pre-Reqs:
Create a dir for you docker/postgres:

```
mkdir -p $HOME/docker/volumes/postgres
```

Example:

```
docker run --rm --name pg-docker -e POSTGRES_USER=<any_desired_name> -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=docker -e POSTGRES_DB=<any_db_name> -d -p 5432:5432 -v $HOME/docker/volumes/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres
```

For postgres username, it can be anything like "super_chain" or etc.
For postgres db, it can be "chainlink"

After, docker is up and running. Just follow up the docs tut, where you need to write the DB URL to the .env file

Cheers